# how to loop through a session object which is a list

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a session object, which contains a list of objects..

```
Session.Add("errorlist",errorlist);
```

Now i want to loop through this errorlist in another function. I tried, but it gives following error:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

This is what I tried:

```
var error = Session["errorlist"];
foreach (var item in error)
{
    //Something here
}
```

I can see a list of objects in "error" variable.

Comment: What are the types of `Session` and `error`?

Comment: what is the datatype of `errorlist`? How did you declare this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything that goes into session is of type `System.Object` by default. So your `var` statement will not have the correct type.

You need to cast it when pulling back out of session.

```
var error = (List<MyObject>)Session["errorlist"];
```

A better way would be to use a safe cast and check for null:

```
var error = Session["errorlist"] as List<MyObject>;

if(error != null){
   //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: And if iterating with `foreach` is all that the OP wants to do with `error`, trying to cast to the general interface `IEnumerable<MyObject>` is probably still a bit safer than to the quite specific type `List<MyObject>`.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Agreed. Unless you plan to modify the collection using the most generic interface is always best.